# Errors when trying to build static library for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have empty static library for iOS (empty, means - I have just one interface defined without any methods), when I try to build it I get bunch of errors like:

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:74:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:120:25: error: expected a type
- (id)initWithIdentity:(SecIdentityRef)identity certificates:(NSArray *)certArray persistence:(NSURLCredentialPersistence) persistence NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 3_0);
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:130:46: error: expected a type
+ (NSURLCredential *)credentialWithIdentity:(SecIdentityRef)identity certificates:(NSArray *)certArray persistence:(NSURLCredentialPersistence)persistence NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 3_0);
                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:137:4: error: expected a type
- (SecIdentityRef)identity;
   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:155:22: error: expected a type
- (id)initWithTrust:(SecTrustRef)trust NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 3_0);
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:162:42: error: expected a type
+ (NSURLCredential *)credentialForTrust:(SecTrustRef)trust NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 3_0);
                                         ^
In file included from /Users/p-kir/Work/SourceRepos/iDev_GIT/Tests/AllTests/AllTests/AllTests-Prefix.pch:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:77:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLProtectionSpace.h:237:4: error: expected a type
- (SecTrustRef)serverTrust NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 3_0);
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`SecIdentityRef` and `SecTrustRef` are defined in the `Security.framework`. Make sure you are importing the proper header file:

```
#import <Security/Security.h>
```

and add the `Security.framework` to your project.